# Switching rootViewController with MMDrawerController: weird behaviour of the transition animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm switching the `rootViewController` of the AppDelegate's window at some point of the app lifecycle. I'm trying to animate such switch this way:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:self.otherViewController.view
                  duration:0.65f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    self.window.rootViewController = self.otherViewController;
                }];
```

Animation is performed but it looks like the second view's height does not fill the screen height, and it suddenly fits the whole screen height once the animation has finished. I hope I've explained properly... what could be happening?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've noticed this behavior appears when `self.otherViewController.view` is a [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController). I tested the code transitioning from a `UINavigationController` to another `UINavigationController` and nothing strange is shown... Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may have come up with a solution here:

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/issues/48